# React hooks 'useState()' updater function with axios.post on form submits

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

Here is my issue: I am using react hooks functional components with the newer `useState` hook. The `useState` hook returns an updater function used to update that state.
The updater function is the issue I am having and this is common knowledge of how React works. The state isn't updated until the `dom` re-renders. But I need to send form data `onSubmit` over `axios` (or `fetch`).

```js
const App = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setUsername(e.target.elements.form1.value)
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api', { name: username })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name="form1" placeholder="Enter name:" />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div >
    )
}
```

In this code when the form is submitted with the `onSubmit` event on the form tag, the `handleSubmit()` function is called. Here the `setUsername()` updater function is going to update the sate and `axios` runs a post call to a backend server. But the `axios.post` will always only send the previous state value because the `setUsername()` function wont finish until the `dom` is re rendered. So the data coming into the backend always appears one step behind.

What is the best method to do this correctly? With my form inputs I don't really need them to be rendered to the `dom`, I just need the form info to be passed to the backend. Should I not even put this data in the state? And if so whats the best way to do this with a large form; say 10 inputs values?

I also have seen people use value={some state value} in the input form for two way binding; but that makes using more then one input in a form very difficult using hooks. Unless there is some magical way I missed.

I have just never seen the 'standard' way of performing `axios` or fetch calls in react with Hooks. I have searched the web a lot but there doesn't seem to be a lot of information on it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

State's updates are asynchronous (with `hooks` the value will only be updated in the next render).

But you already know what `value` looks like cause is inside your scope already. Just pass it to `axios`

```
const App = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const { value } = e.target.elements.form1
        setUsername(value)
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api', { name: value })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name="form1" placeholder="Enter name:" />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div >
    )
}
```